# Nested grouping by epoch time in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

In my pandas dataframe, I group according to ErrorCode and describe latency using

```
data['latency'].groupby(data['ErrorCode']).describe()
```

Which works fine

```
>>> data
     OrderID             Time_req             Time_res  ErrorCode  latency
0    3000013  1488959684403140621  1488959684404694644          1  1554023
1    3000014  1488959685962348449  1488959685962500766          0   152317
2    3000015  1488959727018092829  1488959727018210439          1   117610
3    3000016  1488959731406601811  1488959731406926956          0   325145
4    3000017  1488959734370296179  1488959734370624415          1   328236
```

How do I create a wrapper group by time (with range of say 15 mins) using time from epoch timestamp (can use any Time_req column values)
I used  `datetime.fromtimestamp(1488959684403140621 / 1000000000)`

```
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1488959684403140621 / 1000000000)
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 8, 13, 24, 44)
```

This does give me a human readable time, but how to use it as a grouping range
and then use something like `data.groupby([data['ErrorCode'],pd.TimeGrouper(freq='Min')])` (This is a wrong command I know) But written to show my intent of `grouping by time` then `grouping by ErrorCode` and `describe() latency`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) for convert with unix time to datetetime (default `unit='ns'` can be omit) and then `groupby` with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) and [`describe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.describe.html):

```
data.Time_req = pd.to_datetime(data.Time_req)
data.Time_res = pd.to_datetime(data.Time_res)
#for grouper by Time_res change - data.set_index('Time_res')
data = data.set_index('Time_req')
print (data)
                               OrderID                      Time_res  \
Time_req                                                               
2017-03-08 07:54:44.403140621  3000013 2017-03-08 07:54:44.404694644   
2017-03-08 07:54:45.962348449  3000014 2017-03-08 07:54:45.962500766   
2017-03-08 07:55:27.018092829  3000015 2017-03-08 07:55:27.018210439   
2017-03-08 07:55:31.406601811  3000016 2017-03-08 07:55:31.406926956   
2017-03-08 07:55:34.370296179  3000017 2017-03-08 07:55:34.370624415   

                               ErrorCode  latency  
Time_req                                           
2017-03-08 07:54:44.403140621          1  1554023  
2017-03-08 07:54:45.962348449          0   152317  
2017-03-08 07:55:27.018092829          1   117610  
2017-03-08 07:55:31.406601811          0   325145  
2017-03-08 07:55:34.370296179          1   328236
```

```
df = data.groupby([data['ErrorCode'], pd.Grouper(freq='15T')])['latency'].describe()
print (df)
ErrorCode  Time_req                  
0          2017-03-08 07:45:00  count    2.000000e+00
                                mean     2.387310e+05
                                std      1.222079e+05
                                min      1.523170e+05
                                25%      1.955240e+05
                                50%      2.387310e+05
                                75%      2.819380e+05
                                max      3.251450e+05
1          2017-03-08 07:45:00  count    3.000000e+00
                                mean     6.666230e+05
                                std      7.756932e+05
                                min      1.176100e+05
                                25%      2.229230e+05
                                50%      3.282360e+05
                                75%      9.411295e+05
                                max      1.554023e+06
Name: latency, dtype: float64
```

Also if need reshape add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = data.groupby([data['ErrorCode'],pd.Grouper(freq='15T')])['latency'].describe().unstack()
print (df)
                               count      mean            std       min  \
ErrorCode Time_req                                                        
0         2017-03-08 07:45:00    2.0  238731.0  122207.850779  152317.0   
1         2017-03-08 07:45:00    3.0  666623.0  775693.172568  117610.0   

                                    25%       50%       75%        max  
ErrorCode Time_req                                                      
0         2017-03-08 07:45:00  195524.0  238731.0  281938.0   325145.0  
1         2017-03-08 07:45:00  222923.0  328236.0  941129.5  1554023.0
```

Another solution with [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html):

```
df = data.groupby('ErrorCode').resample('15T')['latency'].apply(lambda x: x.describe())
print (df)
ErrorCode  Time_req                  
0          2017-03-08 07:45:00  count    2.000000e+00
                                mean     2.387310e+05
                                std      1.222079e+05
                                min      1.523170e+05
                                25%      1.955240e+05
                                50%      2.387310e+05
                                75%      2.819380e+05
                                max      3.251450e+05
1          2017-03-08 07:45:00  count    3.000000e+00
                                mean     6.666230e+05
                                std      7.756932e+05
                                min      1.176100e+05
                                25%      2.229230e+05
                                50%      3.282360e+05
                                75%      9.411295e+05
                                max      1.554023e+06
Name: latency, dtype: float64
```

Comment: How do I convey timestamps to be in IST, currently it is converting to GMT time. Thanks

Comment: I think you need check here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#working-with-time-zones - it seems need function `tz_convert`

Comment: Is it possible to have alternate results example https://ideone.com/eeK39b so that every grouped time details for each error are alternating and easy to compare

Comment: do you think solution with `unstack` ? maybe is need only add `reset_index` - `df = data.groupby([data['ErrorCode'],pd.Grouper(freq='15T')])['latency'].describe().unstack().reset_index()`

Comment: The above command puts all errorcode=0  then all errorcode=1 values. Not alternate 0101. want to place same time_req value as one after other thanks (i hope im clear what I mean)

Answer (score 0):

to you use Timegrouper you need to pass the datetime into the index :

```
data.set_index('YOUR_DATE').groupby([data['ErrorCode'],pd.TimeGrouper(freq='Min')])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert one or both "Time_*" columns to `datetime` and use `pd.Grouper()`:

```
In [87]: (df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Time_req, unit='ns'))
    ...:    .groupby(['ErrorCode', pd.Grouper(freq='15T', key='Date')])['latency']
    ...:    .mean()
    ...:    .reset_index(name='avg_latency')
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[87]:
   ErrorCode                Date  avg_latency
0          0 2017-03-08 07:45:00       238731
1          1 2017-03-08 07:45:00       666623
```